# Testing Service Worker Ember Octane

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, service-worker, ember-octane

I am using [ember-service-worker](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-service-worker) to implement offline behavior for my app, so far it does what I need, but I am wondering how can I write some test for my app, to test the service worker is doing his job properly and also because this breaks my current integration tests.

in offline mode I use indexeddb to catch the request and then resync the data when the user have a more stable connection.

thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: How did you get this extension working? Currently they have no docs for it